# Save XML file on Android device and read it

Tags: android, file-io, xml-serialization

I have issues with storing and reading an XML file on my Acer Iconia Tab A 100.

The steps I followed are:

1) Plug in the tab to my system.

2) Copy test.xml file from my laptop to Acer Iconia Tab/ SDCard/ mydir/test.xml

3) Try to open this file in Android code, as follows:

```
   File testFile = null;
   File dir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"mydir");
   if(dir.exists())
   testFile = new File(dir, "test.xml");

   if (testFile != null) 
        Log.d ("File length="+testFile.length());       // returns 0
```

When I execute the above code, it prints out the length as 0. I have tried other combination as follows, but in vain:

```
   File dir = new File("/data","mydir");

   File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard","mydir");
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks.
Ani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File length

```
public long length()
```

Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

**Returns:
        The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist**

So just check it, whether file exist or not,

By using `File.exist();`

Also, By looking in File Explorer -> DDMS via eclipse find the exact path of the file. It also show size of the file.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I had been struggling this with issue since yesterday! This simple answer resolved it! Thanks again!